# Electrons carry the bulk of heat flux in the solar wind?

Tags: electrons, astrophysics, plasma-physics, thermal-conductivity, solar-wind

In the introduction of the attached paper is mentioned that:

> Electrons provide additional heating by carrying the bulk of the solar
> wind heat flux and through collisions with the protons.

[Electron and proton heating by solar wind turbulence](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4074)

What is meant by this phrase?

Comment: This newer research on the solar wind  https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1917905117  may help. This article is descriptive of the new work  https://news.wisc.edu/new-research-helps-explain-why-the-solar-wind-is-hotter-than-expected/ for understanding the role of electrons in the plasma from the sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Electrons provide additional heating by carrying the bulk of the solar wind heat flux and through collisions with the protons.

First, the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) is a weakly collisional [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) at best (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268594/59023).  That is, collisions play an extremely minor role in nearly all processes in the solar wind.  Second, the electron heat flux arises not due to collisions with protons but due the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) and differences in thermal speeds between the two populations.

That is, the electron thermal speed greatly exceeds the [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun)'s gravitational escape speed so they are free to go whenever they move in the anti-sunward direction.  The Lorentz force limits their mobility to being mostly along the quasi-static magnetic field.  Finally, the conservation of the first adiabatic invariant (i.e., magnetic moment of particle gyration) reduces any perpendicular (with respect to quasi-static magnetic field) velocity as the particle moves away from the Sun and the magnetic field strength decreases (e.g., see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/670591/59023).  These effects would take an isotropic, drifting [Maxwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) and turn it into an anisotropic, skewed, narrow, magnetic field-aligned beam.  This population of electrons is known as the *strahl* (German for beam).  See the references below for more discussion.

It is currently thought that the strahl scatters as it propagates away from the sun and forms the other dominant suprathermal electon population in the solar wind called the *halo*.  The cold, dense *core* of the electron population helps to balance the total electric current such that in the plasma rest frame, there is zero net current.  In the core electron rest frame, the heat flux is dominated by the strahl electrons (sometimes the halo helps out too).  In the plasma rest frame, the core electrons can have a rather large heat flux at times in the sunward direction.  Though I don't think this is physically meaningful in the thermodynamic sense since the weakly collisional nature of the solar wind means the particles stream past each other and do not transfer significant energy through collisions via temperature gradients.

> What is meant by this phrase?

This *arXiv* paper is based on a fluid approximation of the solar wind, which would automatically entail particle-particle collisions as a means of energy transfer, i.e., temperature gradients control the heat flux term.

## **References**

- Feldman, W.C., *et al.*, "Electron Velocity Distributions Near the Earth's Bow Shock," *Journal of Geophysical Research* **88**(A1), pp. 96--110, doi:10.1029/JA088iA01p00096, 1983.
- Maksimovic, M., *et al.*, "Ulysses electron distributions fitted with Kappa functions," *Geophysical Research Letters* **24**(9), pp. 1151--1154, doi:10.1029/97GL00992, 1997.
- W.G. Pilipp, et al., "Large-scale variations of thermal electron parameters in the solar wind between 0.3 and 1 AU," *J. Geophys. Res.* **95**(A5), pp. 6305-6329, doi:10.1029/JA095iA05p06305, 1990.
- E.E. Scime, et al., "Regulation of the solar wind electron heat flux from 1 to 5 AU: Ulysses observations," *J. Geophys. Res.* **99**(A12), pp. 23,401-23,410, doi:10.1029/94JA02068, 1994.
- S.J. Schwartz and E. Marsch "The radial evolution of a single solar wind plasma parcel," *J. Geophys. Res.* **88**(A12), pp. 9919-9932, doi:10.1029/JA088iA12p09919, 1983.
- S. Stverak, et al., "Electron energetics in the expanding solar wind via Helios observations," *J. Geophys. Res.* **120**(10), pp. 8177-8193, doi:10.1002/2015JA021368, 2015.
- L.B. Wilson III, et al., "The Statistical Properties of Solar Wind Temperature Parameters Near 1 au," *Astrophys. J. Suppl.* **236**(2), pp. 41, doi:10.3847/1538-4365/aab71c, 2018.
- L.B. Wilson III, et al., "Electron Energy Partition across Interplanetary Shocks. I. Methodology and Data Product," Astrophys. J. Suppl. 243(8), pp. 26, doi:10.3847/1538-4365/ab22bd, 2019a.
- L.B. Wilson III, et al., "Electron Energy Partition across Interplanetary Shocks. II. Statistics," Astrophys. J. Suppl. 245(24), pp. 29, doi:10.3847/1538-4365/ab5445, 2019b.
- L.B. Wilson III, et al., "Electron Energy Partition across Interplanetary Shocks. III. Analysis," Astrophys. J. 893(22), pp. 21, doi:10.3847/1538-4357/ab7d39, 2020.